# How can I write this as a switch statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm having a little trouble trying to rewrite this collection of if statements as a switch statement.

This isn't an exercise or anything, I just really like the look of switch statements. I'm having trouble figuring it out with a function in the if condition on this however.

```
const char* lookup(const char* path)
{
    //if a path exists, compare path to given extensions
    //if there is a match, return the appropriate output
    if (path != NULL) {
        //using strcasecmp is useful b/c capitalization is overlooked when looking for a match
        if (strcasecmp(path, "CSS") == 0) return "text/css";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "HTML") == 0) return "text/html";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "GIF") == 0) return "image/gif";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "ICO") == 0) return "image/x-icon";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "JPG") == 0) return "image/jpeg";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "JS") == 0) return "text/javascript";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "PHP") == 0) return "text/x-php";
        if (strcasecmp(path, "PNG") == 0) return "image/png";
    }
    //if there is no path, return NULL
    return NULL;
}
```

Is it possible to do this, is there any benefit or am I wasting time?

Comment: You kind of could, with a major hack.. I don't recommend it.

Comment: I'm a beginner, not looking to get too crazy just for the sake of it haha

Comment: You can't, not without a direct equals comparison.

Comment: I believe you could do it in a more DRY method, but not with a switch statement -- are you open to that?

Comment: yup, that's what I was going with by trying to implement a switch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have indicated, you can't.  What you can do is make it table-driven, which is probably what @Lambda Ninja intended as more DRY.  Something like this?

```
typedef struct pair_s {
    const char *first;
    const char *second;
} pair;

const char *lookup(const char *path)
{
    static pair content_types[] = {
        { "CSS", "text/css" },
        { "HTML", "text/html" },
        { "GIF", "image/gif" },
        { "ICO", "image/x-icon" },
        // ... etc.
        { "", "" }, // terminator
    };

    for (int i = 0; *content_types[i].first != '\0'; i++) {
        if (strcasecmp(path, content_types[i].first) == 0)
            return content_types[i].second;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because C switch can only test primitive types, you need to map the strings to one of those types.
Happily, the strings you want to test have few enough characters to fit in an int, so you could use the bitwise operators to combine the characters into unique values, testable by switch:

```
#define VAL_CSS  ( ((('C'<<8)|'S')<<8)|'S')
#define VAL_HTML ((((('H'<<8)|'T')<<8)|'M')<<8|'L')
#define VAL_GIF  ( ((('G'<<8)|'I')<<8)|'F')
#define VAL_ICO  ( ((('I'<<8)|'C')<<8)|'O')
#define VAL_JPG  ( ((('J'<<8)|'P')<<8)|'G')
#define VAL_JS   (   ('J'<<8)|'S')
#define VAL_PHP  ( ((('P'<<8)|'H')<<8)|'P')
#define VAL_PNG  ( ((('P'<<8)|'N')<<8)|'G')

const char* lookup(const char* path) { /* "ext" might be a better name than "path" */
  if (path != NULL)
    if (strlen(path) <= sizeof(uint32_t)) { /* check it'll fit */
      uint32_t val = 0;
      while (*path) 
        val = val<<8 | toupper(*path++); /* same as in #defines */

      switch (val) {
        case VAL_CSS:  return "text/css";        break;
        case VAL_HTML: return "text/html";       break;
        case VAL_GIF:  return "image/gif";       break;
        case VAL_ICO:  return "image/x-icon";    break;
        case VAL_JPG:  return "image/jpeg";      break;
        case VAL_JS:   return "text/javascript"; break;
        case VAL_PHP:  return "text/x-php";      break;
        case VAL_PNG:  return "image/png";       break;
      }
    }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Big range of archs have `sizeof(int)==2`, so your code must use fixed width integer types from `<cstdint.h>`. Type `uint32_t` always will have `sizeof(uint32_t)==4`.

Comment: Good point. I did add a check for sizeof(int), and using a long would be better, but the main point of my answer was mapping strings to a form accessible to switch, rather than producing releasable code. I'm new here, so maybe that wasn't ok. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Answer which content only main point it's good for me (imho) and for you (because this save your time), but there exist [some recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and your answer contains some non-critical errors and won't be upvoted by biggest part of users who just copypaste your code.

Comment: @yellowantphil I never normally return in a switch (I'm an only-exit-at-the-bottom-of-the-function kinda guy), so I had some conflict with the requestors in-switch returns and my own need to have breaks.